# File copied to node is empty

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm writing a chef recipe to copy a file to the node and the file is ending up empty, though no errors are reported.

### Details

I'm new to chef and trying to write a recipe to copy a jar file to a Ubuntu box and run it as a service. Generating the init-script for the service from an ERB template is working fine, but trying to use a `file` resource to copy my jar file just produces an empty file on the node.

I'm using kitchen to test out the recipe on a local VM, and kitchen does not report any errors during `kitchen converge`. I'm able to log into the VM with `kitchen login`, but as I mentioned, the jar file is empty.

Here is my block to copy the file:

```
file "SmartTrackChecker-all.jar" do
    action :create
    path "/opt/#{project_name}/#{project_name}.jar"
    owner user_name
    group group_name
    mode 0440
    notifies 'restart', "service[#{service_name}]"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [file](http://docs.chef.io/resource_file.html) resource uses the content specified through the `content` argument - which doesn't seem to be required and default to empty. That's (I guess) why the file is empty.

You want to use the [cookbook_file](http://docs.chef.io/resource_cookbook_file.html) resource instead, which works the same as [template](http://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html) and takes the file from the cookbook's `files/` folder.

I guess the weird naming schema is caused by historic reasons.file

```rb
cookbook_file "SmartTrackChecker-all.jar" do
    action :create
    path "/opt/#{project_name}/#{project_name}.jar"
    owner user_name
    group group_name
    mode 0440
    notifies 'restart', "service[#{service_name}]"
end
```

Comment: I can confirm your first guess, but I do not understand the remark on "weird naming schema", `file` resource is to manage local files (enforcing rights on them without changing their contents for exemple) and `cookbook_file` or `remote_file` are there to distribute remote file (from the cookbook or from remote source), I find this quite logical.

Comment: Well.. Legitimate opinion :-) what about one file provider that covers all cases? At least content and source path/URL. I understand that the might be hard / error prone.

Comment: At least `cookbook_file` vs `template` being irritating for novice users is understandable for new.

Comment: One file provider for all cases would turn complex and error prone yes. For the cookbook_file vs template (with 2 location in the cookbook), I admit it could be better with only one "source directory" and an attribute to tell it's a template)